# How set header under the footer in media queries

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

I have header, some sections and a footer. I want to change position of header to be under my footer when i am in phone media queries (0 to 480px). Is it possible?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code necessary** **in the question itself**, preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` on the parent, then use the `order` property to re-organize in the media query.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  header {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<section>section</section>
<section>section</section>
<section>section</section>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: Exactly what i need! Thank you very much.